# SQL*Plus - Spool into multiple files

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, sqlplus, spool

I've got the next spool that stores the DDL of the `user_tables` into a file:

```
set pagesize 0
set long 90000
spool C:\Users\personal\Desktop\MAIN_USR\test.txt
select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE',table_name,'MAIN_USR')
FROM user_tables ut;
spool off
exit
```

It returns the DDL of all `user_tables` into a single file, but I need it to be a little more dynamic and return them in separate files with the file name of their respective table. Something like this:

```
set pagesize 0
set long 90000
FOR tab_nam IN (SELECT table_name FROM user_tables) LOOP
   spool C:\Users\personal\Desktop\MAIN_USR\test.txt
      select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE',table_name,'MAIN_USR')
      FROM user_tables ut;
   spool off
END LOOP;
exit
```

I know the one above won't work, but it's kind of an idea of what I want to do.

I appreciate any kind of help

Comment: Use a better tool that allow you more control.  Python cx_Oracle comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read USER_TABLES for creating N calls to DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL each of which has its own spooled file. Spool everything to a file named out.sql and run it after spooling it off

```
set pagesize 0
set long 90000

SET TERMOUT OFF
spool out.sql

select 'spool C:\Users\personal\Desktop\MAIN_USR\'||REPLACE(table_name, '$', '_')||'.txt'||chr(13)||chr(10)||
'SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(''TABLE'','''||table_name||''',''MAIN_USR'') FROM DUAL;'||chr(13)||chr(10)||
'spool off' as cmd
FROM user_tables ut;

spool off

@OUT.SQL

exit
```

Comment: It works, but there are some tables that do not return their metadata in the file, unfortunately most of them

Comment: Can you check the "spool off" command is always present after each call to DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL in the OUT.SQl file ?

Comment: It is. I see that the problem is when the spool is assigning a name to each file, since the names appear incomplete

Answer (score 0):

Using python's `cx_Oracle` module which enables access to Oracle Database might be elegant way for your case :

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('uname/pwd@host:port/service_name')
cur = con.cursor()

def OutputTypeHandler(cursor, name, defaultType, size, precision, scale):
    if defaultType == cx_Oracle.CLOB:
        return cursor.var(cx_Oracle.LONG_STRING, arraysize = cursor.arraysize)

cur.outputtypehandler = OutputTypeHandler

cur.execute("select table_name from user_tables order by 1")
rec = cur.fetchall()

for r in rec:
    cur.execute("select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE',:tableName) from dual",tableName=r[0])
    ddl, = cur.fetchone()

    file = r'C:\\Users\\personal\\Desktop\\MAIN_USR\\'+r[0]+'.txt' 

    with open(file,"w") as f:
            f.write(ddl)
    f.close()
```

where the table names of the whole schema are determined through the first `cur.execute`, and their creation DDL are done in the second, and files are created with respective table names at the last step. Important thing to consider is related to use of `OutputTypeHandler` is because of getting rid of processing the CLOB result steming from `Dbms_Metadata.Get_Ddl` function. The compiler wouldn't want to get a CLOB value during the creation of the files, or DDL would be so long that will exceed the length 4000 chars which would prevent to_char conversion with raising error without using `OutputTypeHandler`.